# Something intercepting java2d paint calls?

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I have a Java Swing application, which when under stress (slow/backlogged event queue), logs out stack traces of what it's doing.  Recently something interesting appeared that I have not seen before:

```
"AWT-EventQueue-2" Id=78 RUNNABLE (in native)
at com.imprivata.Interceptor.log(Native Method)
at com.imprivata.Interceptor.sun_java2d_SunGraphics2D_fillRect(Interceptor.java)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.fillRect(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
```

Has anyone run into Imprivata (http://www.imprivata.com/) before?  It seems to be some kind of SSO application, but why would it be intercepting java2d calls?

Answer (score 0):

There are no interceptions in the [OpenJDK source of SunGraphics2D](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u40/jdk/file/437de3b8d317/src/share/classes/sun/java2d/SunGraphics2D.java), so this must be injected (possibly using [Java EE interceptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkigq.html)) from your libraries. Check your jars for com.imprivata classes, and then ask the author of the containing jar.